# Diagonal line in math arrays

Tags: tables, arrays, diagbox

I have some arrays in math mode, such as the one below. I would like a diagonal line in a cell, something like `diagbox` (diagbox package) or `diaghead` (makecell package). But it seems that `diagbox` and `diaghead` only work in a `tabular` environment. Of course a way to go consists in using `tabular` instead of `array` but this requires to put some `$`'s in each cell. I'm looking for a less tedious solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}

$$
\begin{array}{r|cccc}
%\diagbox{x}{y} 
& (0,0) & (0,1) & (1,0) & (1,1) \\ 
  \hline
(0,0) & \phi^{-1}  &  \frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}} - \phi^{-1} & 0  & \frac{f_{n+1}}{f_{n-1}} \\ 
(0,1) & f_{n}/f_{n-1} & 0 & f_{n+1}/f_{n-1} & 0 \\ 
(1,0) & \phi^{-1}  & \phi^{-2}  & 0 & 0 \\ 
(1,1) & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array} 
$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't M. Al Jumaily's answer sufficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just encapsulate `\diagbox{x}{y}` inside an `\hbox{}`, *i.e.*, `\hbox{\diagbox{x}{y}}`. Also, you can surround the text with `$...$` to ensure the text is in mathmode as such: `\hbox{\diagbox{$x$}{$y$}}`. Off-topic, you should be using `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$` (have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)).

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{diagbox}
\begin{document}
\noindent\ Without \$...\$
\[
    \begin{array}{r|cccc}
        \hbox{\diagbox{x}{y}} & (0,0) & (0,1) & (1,0) & (1,1) \\ \hline
        (0,0) & \phi^{-1}  &  \frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}} - \phi^{-1} & 0  & \frac{f_{n+1}}{f_{n-1}} \\ 
        (0,1) & f_{n}/f_{n-1} & 0 & f_{n+1}/f_{n-1} & 0 \\ 
        (1,0) & \phi^{-1}  & \phi^{-2}  & 0 & 0 \\ 
        (1,1) & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    \end{array} 
\]
With \$...\$
\[
    \begin{array}{r|cccc}
        \hbox{\diagbox{$x$}{$y$}} & (0,0) & (0,1) & (1,0) & (1,1) \\ \hline
        (0,0) & \phi^{-1}  &  \frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}} - \phi^{-1} & 0  & \frac{f_{n+1}}{f_{n-1}} \\ 
        (0,1) & f_{n}/f_{n-1} & 0 & f_{n+1}/f_{n-1} & 0 \\ 
        (1,0) & \phi^{-1}  & \phi^{-2}  & 0 & 0 \\ 
        (1,1) & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    \end{array} 
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better solution: since diagbox always use \tabcolsep and \arraycolsep may have a different value, we need to do this:

`\newcommand\mydiagbox[2]{\hbox{\tabcolsep=\arraycolsep\diagbox{$#1$}{$#2$}}}`

Then we can use `\mydiagbox{X}{Y}` inside array environment.

Answer (score 0):

The package `nicematrix` provides its own built-in command `\diagbox` in all its environments: `{NiceTabular}`, `{NiceArray}`, `{pNiceMatrix}`, etc.

Here, you might use `{NiceArray}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceArray}{r|cccc}
\diagbox{x}{y} 
& (0,0) & (0,1) & (1,0) & (1,1) \\ 
  \hline
(0,0) & \phi^{-1}  &  \frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}} - \phi^{-1} & 0  & \frac{f_{n+1}}{f_{n-1}} \\ 
(0,1) & f_{n}/f_{n-1} & 0 & f_{n+1}/f_{n-1} & 0 \\ 
(1,0) & \phi^{-1}  & \phi^{-2}  & 0 & 0 \\ 
(1,1) & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{NiceArray}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]